# Storyboard and Segue

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a question for segue.
I have a tabbar controller which is checking if the user is logged in. If they're not it will load another view controller (using a segue) for the login. Now on the login screen I have a register button which is loading another segue button for register. So my connection until now is: TabbarController->LoginController->RegisterController. Now if the user has successfully registered I want to go back to tabbar. If I use a segue from RegisterController to the TabbarControl is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter if you are using a UIStoryBoardSegue or something else, what matters is how you a re displaying everything.

UIStoryBoardSegues can push view controllers to navigation controllers (horizontal movement) or present modal view controllers (vertical movement).

Normally you would want to have your login segue show a UINavigationController with your login controller inside. Then you can push your register controller on top of that.

When you want to dismiss either your login controller or your register controller you can just do

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I dont want to use navigation controller. I am using modal to show logincontroller from tabbar and then modal to show register from login

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty straightforward technique to achieve this.
Your `UITabBar` can present login view using **modal** segue. Transitions between login and register view may be **push** segue. And when user logged in or registered you can dismiss login or register view using `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
In this way you don't need any segues from login or register view back to `UITabBar`.
You can store login information in AppDelegate or some another class.

Comment: I am using modal segue from Tabbar to LoginController and another modal segue from LoginController to RegisterController. I dont want to use navigation controller. So I need to do this in [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; REgisterController and another dismissView in LoginController?